# How can I change the width/thickness of a scrollbar?

Tags: android, scrollbar, android-scrollview, android-scrollbar

Currently this is my `scrollbar.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:centerColor="@color/blue"
        android:endColor="@color/blue"
        android:startColor="@color/blue" />

    <corners android:radius="8dp" />

</shape>
```

And this is my ScrollView:

```xml
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnBack" >
```

This is the scrollbar it gives me. It's good, except it's too thick and obvious. It may not look thick in this screenshot, but it really is.

[image]

Am I able to set a ScrollView property to adjust the width/thickness of the scrollbar? Or can I put a property in my gradient?

Comment: Have you tried reducing the size of radius ?

Comment: @GrIsHu the radius determines the roundness on the top and bottom of the scrollbar. Not the width of the scrollbar. But yes I've tried anyways.

Comment: You may wanna take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103132/android-listview-scrollbarstyle/50614021#50614021)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

add the following property to your layout

```
android:scrollbarSize="50dip"
```

Answer (score 9):

see the `android:scrollbarSize=""` attribute of `ScrollView`.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnBack"
    android:scrollbarSize="4dp"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar" >
```

Comment: Perfect size even lol. I asked this in a comment on another post and Dehan said he would answer if I posted a question. I'll accept his, but I'll browse through your previous questions/answer and give you some votes. Thanks.

Comment: @mikeyaworski Really glad to help you... but don't upvote other answers of me as a result of this answer... (really I don't like that way) If it helped you, you can upvote this. and thank you

Comment: Sure, just wanted to pass on reputation where it's deserved.

Answer (score 3):

For making very easy and using many times, same type of scrollbar in list view, use as a style and color in style.xml and color.xml in values folder.

i.e. in Android Studio :

> Project_Name/app/main/res/values

and the code in

> style.xml

```
 <resources>    
   <style name="mScrollBar">
     <item name="android:scrollbarSize">1dp</item>
     <item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@color/base_color</item>
   </style>
 </resources>
```

> in color.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
     <color name="Salmon">#FA8072</color>
 </resources>
```