# extra space in real device

Tags: android, xml

This might look obvious but it has defeated me. When i run my app on a real device, there is an extra space of about 2mm to the right of the screen that is never fills up with my layout. Where am i going wrong? I will appreciate your advice.

below is my xml file and attached is a screenshot 
[image: extra space on the right side]
of the displayed activity;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
android:fadeScrollbars="true"
android:scrollbarSize="10dip"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#E6EDD7">

<TextView
     android:id="@+id/SignInOut"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="16dp"
     android:text="@string/SignInOut"
     android:textColor="#000080"
     android:textSize="12sp"          
     android:layout_gravity="right"  
     android:layout_marginTop="1dp"               
     />


<TextView
     android:id="@+id/Title"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
     android:textColor="#0000FF"
     android:textSize="12sp"
     android:textStyle="bold" 
     />

<TextView
     android:id="@+id/VSLA"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="32dp"
     android:text="@string/VSLA"
     android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
     android:textSize="18sp"
     android:textStyle="bold" 
     android:background="#000000"/>

<HorizontalScrollView
android:id="@+id/HA"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
android:fadeScrollbars="true"
android:scrollbarSize="10dip"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >




<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/District"
    android:layout_width="155dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/District_arrays"
    android:prompt="@string/District_prompt"
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/SubCounty" />

    <requestFocus />


<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/SubCounty"
    android:layout_width="155dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/SubCounty_arrays"
    android:prompt="@string/SubCounty_prompt"
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/Parish" />



</TableRow>

</HorizontalScrollView>



<HorizontalScrollView
android:id="@+id/HL"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
android:fadeScrollbars="true"
android:scrollbarSize="10dip"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/Parish"
    android:layout_width="155dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/Parish_arrays"
    android:prompt="@string/Parish_prompt"
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/Village" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/Village"
    android:layout_width="155dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/Village_arrays"
    android:prompt="@string/Village_prompt"
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
     />

</TableRow>

</HorizontalScrollView>



<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/Home"
    android:background="@drawable/home" 
    android:layout_width="50dip" 
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/Home"
    android:layout_gravity="center"        
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/CancelBtn"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:text="@string/CancelBtn" 
    android:textSize="26sp"  
    android:layout_gravity="center"   
    android:textStyle="bold"   
    />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/Save"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:text="@string/Save" 
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />

</TableRow>


</LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Screenshot not showing for me.

Comment: [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/sc/yevpfseaayuz7t3/AADJ7qwzFjjyO1Oo3GEyhUMXa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"` to `android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay". For more details, [see this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14494238/1528969)