# WebView not scrolling in API 30

Tags: android, html, android-layout, kotlin, webview

I have a html file in WebView and it only contains text. It's not scrolling API 30 device(emulator). But it's scrolling other devices below api 30.

xml:

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" i tried match_parent and 0dp
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/divider" />
```

I also tried:

```
           android:scrollbars="vertical" (xml)
           webView.isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = true (programatic)
```

and tried yo use FrameLayout or ScrollView but still it didn't work.
By the way I load an asset file:

```
           webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Agreement.html")
```

And this is example structure of html file:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Agreement</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>some texts... with <i> tag sometimes.... there are 2 paragraph </p>
    </html>
```

Comment: Try to load some web pages.

Comment: @SahilGoyal yeah it's scrolling another web site. So maybe there is a problem with my html file. But I don't understand it's only simple text and it's working other devices.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the default behavior changes of [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) scrolling [`API 30`](https://developer.android.com/reference).

The [`API 30`](https://developer.android.com/reference) [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) is handled by [`ScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView) Parent. If it doesn't exist it is handled by [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView).

---

You have to disable the [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) scroll:

```
webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

---

Wrap [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) inside [`ScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView) and set the height `match_parent`:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</ScrollView>
```

---

Add the following attribute to the [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) in the `.xml` layout if you're using [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout):

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constrainedHeight="true" />
```

---

Add the [`android:scrollbars`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView) and [`android:scrollbarStyle`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103132/android-listview-scrollbarstyle) attributes to [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) in your `.xml` layout:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay" />
```

---

Check if the content from inside [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) exceeds the height screen.

---

Use a different `layout` like [`LinearLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout) or [`RelativeLayout`](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/relative) that may resolve the issue:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

Verify the custom styles applied to [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) that can conflict:

1. Open `styles.xml` in `res/values` directory.
2. Check custom styles. (They could have a parent [`Widget.WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView))
3. Check if custom styles conflicts or if they set the `height` or `width`.
4. Remove or modify to see if it resolves the scroll.